# How to make live preview based on information entered in a form? PhP/ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm working on one project and it would be very handy to implement "live preview" feature in it. The problem is it is not some kind of typed text preview "e.g. one like on stackoverflow when you create a question". What I am working on is slightly different. For example, I have a form with inputs like (background color, padding value, margin value etc...) Each time user updates one of those inputs I wan't to show preview of updated object next to the form, Lets say this object is div styled basing on what user entered in a form.

How can I achieve this feature?

jQuery based solution is preferable.

**Edit:** say this is how form looks

```
<form id="div_builder">
   <input type="text" name="background_color"/>
   <input type="text" name="padding"/>
   <input type="text" name="margin"/>
</form>
```

Comment: So what is the actual problem? Update the preview div on each field value change with javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not testet but should work (with jquery)...

```
<form id="div_builder">
   <input type="text" name="background-color"/>
   <input type="text" name="padding"/>
   <input type="text" name="margin"/>
</form>

<div id="object"><img src="some object" /></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#div_builder input').change(function(){
   var css = $(this).attr("name");
   $("#object").css(css,$(this).val());
})
</script>
```

Comment: Why `.attr("value")` and not `.val()`, just curious

Comment: where you mention .attr("name") Do you mean name of an input correct? So basically I would copy your code 3 times for each input and change "name" and css "value" right?

Comment: no it catches all inputs in the given form... the name of the input have to be the name of the css value it should change. dont change something in the function, it will wor as it is

Comment: @zerkms i use attr("value") often because some fields doesnt support .val()

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work. maybe I'm doing something wrong, here is what I have so far http://jsfiddle.net/yUKQ4/1/ I think it could be .vak part, how do I add value from input in there?

Comment: it works there... have you set the framework to jquery and clicked the run button on the top?

Comment: True, I forgot to set it to jQuery, it works! one question it updates only when I pres enter, is there a way to update it every time a new character is added in inputs?

Comment: fields? in the function: $('#div_builder input').keyup(function(){

Answer (score 2):

the [change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/) is your friend. On each change, call a function that assigns the chosen attributes to the div you want to display.